# KB articles directly pointing to external link - Servicenow

Tags: servicenow, knowledge-management

I have got a requirement: KB article should directly link/point to an external URL.

Details:

When an end user clicks on a KB article in Knowledge base, he should be directly redirected to an external link rather than opening the KB article in ServiceNow.

I have provided an external link inside the article, so the end user can open the article and then click the link to re-direct. But the user does not want to open the article, but wants to go directly to external URL.

I know the requirement is a bit weird. Let me know if anyone has an experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the user via Client Script to the external URL:

1. User clicks on the knowledge article
2. Knowledge articles opens and
3. On Load Client Script executing with URL call.

If you can call the URL early enough, the user will not see the article.

Answer (score 2):

It used to be a lot more customisable in Knowledge v2 as you could simply edit the kb_find UI Page. However, in Knowledge v3 the interface is more complex and is not published in a customer-editable UI Page for this and other reasons.

Like the other answer on here, you could hack together a Macgyver-style solution with global UI Scripts, however the downside to doing this is that as new releases come out you make have to keep re-engineering the solution as it's likely to break as the interface changes, and if it breaks permanently you might have to field a lot of calls from users complaining about it.

Best to stick with as close to out-of-box as possible I would say.